# Issue while flattening annotations in a pdf using Itext or PDFBox. Currently I'm trying using IText 7.2.3

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, itext7

I have a requirement where I need to flatten all the annotations present in the PDF. I'm trying to loop through all the stamp annotations and then adding that annotation as an image in PDF directly. The code I'm using is working fine for normal PDFs, but it is failing for rotated page PDFs.
Below is the code I'm using to add stamp annotations to the PDF :

```
        String dest = "ITEXT_NEW_DOC.pdf";       
          PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest); 
          PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);              
          PdfPage page = pdfDoc.addNewPage();               
          page.setRotation(0);
          Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);               
          document.add(new Paragraph("Hello world, this is a test pdf file."));
          document.close();

        PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(new File(dest));
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader1, new PdfWriter("ITEXT_STAMP_ADDED.pdf"), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
        String filePath = "new_rectangle.png";

        ImageData img = ImageDataFactory.create(filePath);
        PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        if (rotation == 90) 
        {
            xObj.put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new int[]{0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0}));
        }
        else if(rotation == 270)
        {
            xObj.put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new int[]{0,  -1, 1, 0, 0, 0}));
        }
        else if (rotation == 180) 
        {
            xObj.put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new int[]{-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}));
        }
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,300,250);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj, doc);
        canvas.addImageAt(img, 0, 0,false);
        PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(rect);
        stamp.setNormalAppearance(xObj.getPdfObject());
        int flag = PdfAnnotation.LOCKED_CONTENTS | PdfAnnotation.READ_ONLY
                | PdfAnnotation.LOCKED | PdfAnnotation.PRINT ;
        stamp.setFlags(flag);
        stamp.setName(new PdfString("TestStamp1"));
        doc.getPage(1).addAnnotation(stamp);

        ImageData img1 = ImageDataFactory.create(filePath);
        PdfFormXObject xObj1 = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight()));
        if (rotation == 90) 
        {
            xObj1.put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new int[]{0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0}));
        }
        else if(rotation == 270)
        {
            xObj1.put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new int[]{0,  -1, 1, 0, 0, 0}));
        }
        else if (rotation == 180) 
        {
            xObj1.put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new int[]{-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}));
        }
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100,400,300,250);
        PdfCanvas canvas1 = new PdfCanvas(xObj1, doc);
        canvas1.addImageAt(img1, 0, 0,false);
        PdfStampAnnotation stamp1 = new PdfStampAnnotation(rect1);
        stamp1.setNormalAppearance(xObj1.getPdfObject());
        int flag1 = PdfAnnotation.LOCKED_CONTENTS | PdfAnnotation.READ_ONLY
                | PdfAnnotation.LOCKED | PdfAnnotation.PRINT ;
        stamp1.setFlags(flag1);
        stamp1.setName(new PdfString("TestStamp2"));
        doc.getPage(1).addAnnotation(stamp1);

        
        doc.close();
    
        System.out.println("COMPLETED");
```

Once the stamp added PDF is created, I'm using the below code to flatten them:

```
          String src="ITEXT_STAMP_ADDED.pdf";
          String dest="ITEXT_STAMP_FLATTENED.pdf";
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) 
            {
                PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
                PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
                List<PdfAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
                for (PdfAnnotation annot : annotations) 
                {
                    if(annot instanceof PdfStampAnnotation)
                    {
                        PdfDictionary appearanceObject = annot.getAppearanceObject(PdfName.N);
                        if (appearanceObject != null) 
                        {
                            PdfFormXObject appearanceXObj = new PdfFormXObject((PdfStream) appearanceObject.clone());
                            Rectangle rect = annot.getRectangle().toRectangle();
                            canvas.addXObjectFittedIntoRectangle(appearanceXObj, rect);
//using addXObject was not working at all, so used fit into rectangle.
//                      canvas.addXObject(appearanceXObj, rect.getX(), rect.getY());
                            page.removeAnnotation(annot);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Flatten the acroform
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
            form.flattenFields();
            document.close();
            System.out.println("COMPLETED");
```

The above code is fine for normal pdfs, but for rotated PDFs this isn't working fine. I'm getting the rotated images in the resulting PDF. Can anyone let us know what can be done so that the input PDF and the resulting PDF should looks same?

I'm even ok with using PDFBox to achieve this.

Attaching the files generated and images used:

[new_rectangle.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IDHzR3Qkao99B0XjHeodPNTKhLxegBtx/view?usp=sharing)

[ITEXT_0_STAMP_ADDED.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QqxVf_wRePpJxDyq8vhQxUH83e7bP1zS/view?usp=sharing)

[ITEXT_0_STAMP_FLATTENED.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZNxmXe2gYZTcfjVJ02hGAyhOO2RdsSL/view?usp=sharing)

[ITEXT_180_STAMP_ADDED.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lhzDjoLclP2BgcgdiH07MJES3JxfCXL9/view?usp=sharing)

[ITEXT_180_STAMP_FLATTENED.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XPd0TZQTFrwUSUcUiEPRI4E7tVTIoG5f/view?usp=sharing)

[ITEXT_270_STAMP_ADDED.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXy29tm-wkGQs5Kt81a5aAlk9MQRxkSm/view?usp=sharing)

[ITEXT_270_STAMP_FLATTENED.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aoBxTVaxTk_0OVHmq5ZA4QeEbV--hioU/view?usp=sharing)

All the above code is in IText-7.2.3 version.